# Memory layout in Linux - system() behaviour

Tags: c, linux, memory, layout, system-calls

I compiled on Slackware 14 (32 bit) the following sample programs:

```
// p1.c
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned char *sp() { asm("movl %esp, %eax\n\taddl $8,  %eax"); }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
   char *s1="1111111111";
   printf("p1:  s1=%p,  SP=%p\n", s1, sp());
   system("./p2.bin");
   printf("p1:  s1=%p,  SP=%p\n", s1, sp());
   }

// p2.c
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned char *sp() { asm("movl %esp, %eax\n\taddl $8,  %eax"); }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
   char *s2="2222222222";
   printf("p2:  s2=%p,  SP=%p\n", s2, sp());
   }
```

ESP printed values were identical:
`bash-4.2$ ./p1.bin`
`p1:  s1=0x8048580,  SP=0xbffff6b0`
`p2:  s2=0x8048530,  SP=0xbffff6b0`
`p1:  s1=0x8048580,  SP=0xbffff6b0`
But I expected different ones, because p2 main function's stack frame should be allocated on top of p1 main function's stack frame. What's wrong?

Another question:
If I modify p2.c to dump memory from 0x8048580 I can see "2222222222" (now at addrress 0x80486f0) but not "1111111111" at 0x8048580. Why?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p2 is an entirely different process. It is not 'allocated on top of p1'. Even though the addresses are the same, they actually refer to different physical memory locations. This is all hidden by virtual memory and the MMU of the CPU.

The reason the values are the same has to do with how linux loads executables. Do not rely on them being the same always.